# php array into multidimensional array keys

Tags: php, arrays

How do I turn this:

```
  $keys=array(1,8,27);
```

Into this?

```
    $array=array();
    $array[1][8][27]='Hooray!';
```

I have an array that I need as the keys of a multidimensional array.
In the  example:
     I am using 1, 8 and 27.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
$array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]] = "Hooray!";
```

Can't even begin to imagine how to go about making it dynamic though.